# What is the value of $f''(1-i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

If $$f(a)=\oint_C\frac{3z^2+7z+1}{z-a}dz$$ where $C$ is the circle $|z|=2$, find

$(i)$ $f(1-i),$

$(ii)$ $f''(1-i),$

$(iii)$ $f(1+i).$

I am able to do first and third parts. Please help me with the second part.

What is the value of $f''(1-i)$.

Will it be zero or not exist since $1-i$ is a pole, or $12\pi i$?

Comment: Please use MathJax.  It is really hard to read this.

Comment: Hint: find $f(a)$ for $|a| < 2$ using the Residue Theorem, and take the second derivative.

Comment: Why would you think $1-i$ is a pole?

Comment: @RobertIsrael if we don't take it as pole, we can't find f(a) by applying Cauchy Residue Theorem

Comment: And using Cauchy integral formula ? $f(z) = 2\pi i (3z^2+7z+1)$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean: the pole of the integrand (when $a = 1-i$), not of $f(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Cauchy's Integral formula...
$$ f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{2\pi i(3z^2 + 7z+1)}{z-a}\,\mathrm dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\;\mathrm dz$$
I'd say that $f(z) = 2\pi i(3z^2 + 7z+1)$... then

i) $f(1-i) = 26\pi + 16\pi i$

ii) $f''(1-i) = 12\pi i$

iii) $f(1+i) = -26\pi +16\pi i$

Answer (score 0):

[Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) states that if a complex function $f(z)$ is analytic in an open domain $S$, and if the closed disk $D=\{z:|z-z'|\le \rho\}$ is contained in $S$, then for any number $a$ inside $D$

$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-z'|=\rho} \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz \tag1$$

---

Note that $f(z)=3z^2+7z+1$ is an entire function and is therefore analytic in an on the closed disk $|z|\le 2$.  Using $(1)$ with $f(z)=3z^2+7z+1$, $z'=0$, $\rho=2$, then for $|a|<2$ we have

$$3a^2+7a+1=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{3z^2+7z+1}{z-a}\,dz\tag 2$$

Moreover, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that for $|a|>2$

$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{3z^2+7z+1}{z-a}\,dz=0 \tag3$$

Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ together yields

$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{3z^2+7z+1}{z-a}\,dz=\begin{cases}2\pi i (3a^2+7a+1)&,|a|<2\\\\0&,|a|>2\end{cases} $$

Therefore, we find that

$$f''(a)=\frac{d^2}{da^2}\left.\left(\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{3z^2+7z+1}{z-a}\,dz\right)\right|_{a=1-i} \begin{cases}12\pi i&,|a|<2\\\\0&,|a|>2\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion given by Robert Israel is very good, of course. Another way of computing $f(a)$ is\begin{align*}f(a)&=\oint_C\frac{3z^2+7z+1}{z-a}\mathrm dz\\&=\oint_C\frac{3z^2+7z+1-(3a^2+7a+1)}{z-a}\mathrm dz+\oint_C\frac{3a^2+7a+1}{z-1}\mathrm dz\\&=\oint_C\frac{3(z-a)(z+a)+7(z-a)}{z-a}\mathrm dz+2\pi i(3a^2+7a+1)\operatorname{Ind}_C(a)\\&=\oint_C3(z+a)+7\,\mathrm dz+2\pi i(3a^2+7a+1)\text{ (if $|a|<2$)}\\&=2\pi i(3a^2+7a+1).\end{align*}Therefore, $f''\equiv12\pi i$ (in $D(0,2)$).

Comment: You've tacitly assumed that $|a|<2$.  Of course, from Cauchy's Integral Theorem, $f(a)=0$, for $|a|>2$.  And for $|a|=2$, $f(a)$ is not defined, but can assigned a value in terms of a Cauchy Principal Value.  I posted a solution slightly before you posted yours that provides the details. ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola No, I did *not* tacitly assume that $|a|<2$; I stated that hypothesis *explicitly*. Since the goal was to compute $f''(1-i)$ and since $|1-i|<2$, working within the disk $D(0,2)$ was enough for me.

Comment: I missed the stated hypothesis in the development of your expression for $f(a)$.  I would suggest stating it upfront rather than writing it parenthetically after the penultimate result.  I believe that would be helpful for future readers.